# Do I need to change host header values if DNS entry changes

Tags: domain-name-system, iis

We are migrating to a new website & domain name. Current and new website have two different are located on two different machines.  If DNS entries are changed to point old domain name to new server, do I even need to change the host header values on old IIS server? In a couple of days after the switch over we are planing to stop old IIS site from running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you need to configure the new machine properly.

The host header does not describe the machine, it describes the domain that should be shown.